# Angular Directive with ng-include to html templateUrl not showing error messages

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-directive, angularjs-digest, ng-messages

If I put this html/angular/css code in line and click on Submit Request Button it highlights in red and shows the error message properly

```
<div class="col-md-12" style="margin-top: 5px;">
    <div class="form-group-sm" ng-class="{'has-error': (orderDetailsForm.CustomerNameKey.$invalid && orderDetailsForm.CustomerNameKey.$touched) || (orderDetailsForm.CustomerNameKey.$invalid && vmRequest.submittingRequest)}">
        <label class="col-md-2 control-label text-nowrap">Customer Name Key:</label>
        <lcd-code lcdcode="{{ detail.program.lcdCode }}"></lcd-code>

        <div class="col-md-3" ng-class="{'has-error': (orderDetailsForm.CustomerNameKey.$invalid && orderDetailsForm.CustomerNameKey.$touched) || (orderDetailsForm.CustomerNameKey.$invalid && vmRequest.submittingRequest)}">
            <input replace="[^a-zA-Z]" with="" maxlength="4" type="text" id="CustomerNameKey" name="CustomerNameKey" class="form-control" ng-model="detail.customerNameKey" placeholder="Customer Name Key" required />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group-sm">
        <div class="col-md-5">
            <span ng-messages="orderDetailsForm.CustomerNameKey.$error" ng-if="(orderDetailsForm.CustomerNameKey.$invalid && orderDetailsForm.CustomerNameKey.$touched) || (orderDetailsForm.CustomerNameKey.$invalid && vmRequest.submittingRequest)">
                <span ng-message="required" class="label label-danger">Customer Name Key is required.</span>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">

    </div>
</div>
```

Now Instead if I put in a custom `Directive`

and replace above code with this

```
<div ng-if="detail.program.ldcCode.length > 0">
     <lcd-code lcdcode="{{ detail.program.ldcCode }}"></lcd-code>
</div>
```

This directive will call an ng-include with the html template of that same code.  However now if i click on the submit button the error handling doesn't work,

**Is this part of the Angular loading of the digest cycle of the DOM and being aware of what needs to be "watched"**

**How can i fix this?**

**Directive**

```
(function () {

    var injectParams = ['customerService', '$sce'];

    var lcdCode = function (customerService, $sce) {
        return {
            replace: true,
            restrict: "E",
            scope: {
                lcdcode: '@'
            },
            //template: '<div ng-bind-html="content"></div>', //'<div>blah</div>',
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                var promise = customerService.getKey(attrs.lcdcode)
                    .then(function (result) {
                        //scope.content = result;

                        //scope.content = $sce.trustAsHtml(blah);
                        scope.url = "";

                        scope.getContentUrl = function () {
                            if (result === 1) {
                                scope.url = '/app/request/templates/keyRequired.html?v=1';
                            } else {
                                scope.url = '/app/request/templates/empty.html?v=1';
                            }
                            return scope.url;
                        }

                        //console.log('scope.content', scope.content);
                    })
                    .catch(function () {
                        console.log('problem');
                    });

            },
            template: '<div ng-include="getContentUrl()"></div>'
            //template: '<div ng-bind-html="content"></div>'
        };
    };

    lcdCode.$inject = injectParams;

    angular.module('app').directive('lcdCode', lcdCode)

}());
```

MOST relevant parts are

```
  template: '<div ng-include="getContentUrl()"></div>'
```

which calls and loads the exact html div structure i pasted

```
  scope.url = '/app/request/templates/keyRequired.html?v=1';
```

Comment: Could you post the code of that directive.

Comment: @TimConsolazio   -  added to question    -  Thx Tim

Comment: Just for the heck of it, don't load the fragment from a function. Just get the html and put it in the template of the directive. I get you may want to load different fragments, but it would be interesting to factor that out of the equation for now.

Comment: I started reading earlier about other people having trouble losing scope in directives with ng-includes... and that ngmessages seem to be an issue too in that passing the Form is advised or changing link or even compiler ...

Comment: I've used ng-includes to load fragments, and they could access the variables in the controller of the template that loaded them just fine. But you're trying to do something in excess of that. I suspect rethinking your structure would be the way to go, but I would at least start by not loading that fragment into an include by way of a function.